# Android Image caching

Tags: java, android

I have a dynamic View Flipper creating the view with image of 250kb. The total view is 60. I am getting a Out of memory error. I have the images stored in draw able folder. I have an example code of Lazy loader but it loads from url. I want to change the function to fetch from dawable folder instead of remote url. Here is my code. Could any body help?

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    //CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    // Download image file from web
    try {

        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();


        // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to file
        // if file not exist then it will create file
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

        // See Utils class CopyStream method
        // It will each pixel from input stream and
        // write pixels to output stream (file)
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);

        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();

        //Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
        // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);

        return bitmap;

    } catch (Throwable ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }


}
//Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){

    try {

        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1=new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1,null,o);
        stream1.close();

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

        // Set width/height of recreated image
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=85;

        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with current scale values
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        FileInputStream stream2=new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use Picasso library to handle this, it wil do everything for you

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.drawableName).into(imageView);
```

In your adapter :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.drawableName).into(imageView);
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```

Link: https://github.com/square/picasso

Or if you still not like to use Picasso, let's comment, i'll share you some class to modify image, save to cache and load up, but it so long...

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. I am new to Android. Could you please tell me how to install it in to my project. For your reference I am using Android Studio.

Comment: In the build.gradle (Module app) in your project, add following line:  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'  into depedencies { ... } . And then click sync project. Finished

Comment: Hi, I am using the following
 Uri url = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + fileName);
 Picasso.with(mContext).load(url).into(phraseImage);
But it is giving the following warning with no image loaded
W/ResourceType﹕ No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

Comment: I've checked, it load fine ("android.resource://my.package.here/drawable/imageName"). In my opinion, your uri can be wrong, try to check Picasso image loader with online image uri or resource Id (R.drawable.imageName). If it work, check your uri, and replace (mContext.getPackageName()) with characters like me, and in imageName, dont include extend image type (",jpg" or ".png")

Answer (score 1):

`Universal Image Loader` is made on top of `Picasso` and provides greater caching and loading features. More info can be found on https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader . For setup.

Include `compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'` in your `build.gradle` file. Then include the following configurations in `MyApplication extends Application` class

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
        .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
        .taskExecutor(...)
        .taskExecutorForCachedImages(...)
        .threadPoolSize(3) // default
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2) // default
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
        .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
        .memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
        .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(cacheDir)) // default
        .diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
        .diskCacheFileCount(100)
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
        .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
        .imageDecoder(new BaseImageDecoder()) // default
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
        .writeDebugLogs()
        .build();
```

And then use it as

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Hope this helps.